# How to change the email notification recipient (user) for new comments?

Tags: comments, user-roles, email, notifications, moderation

How do you change the user that gets the notification email announcement for new comments and comment moderation?

WordPress sends the notices to the *admin* user. My client is the editor of the site. I want the comment notices to get mailed to the editor user and not the *admin* user.

How do you do that?

Comment: Did either answer help you?  If so then please consider accepting one.

Answer (score 10):

There's a great article explaining how to hook into 2 filters for this at https://web.archive.org/web/20200216075253/http://www.sourcexpress.com/customize-wordpress-comment-notification-emails/

To send your notifications to a particular user and not the site admin, try this for a user with ID 123:

```
function se_comment_moderation_recipients( $emails, $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', '123' );

    // Return only the post author if the author can modify.
    if ( user_can( $user->ID, 'edit_published_posts' ) && ! empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
        $emails = array( $user->user_email );
    }

    return $emails;
}
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any hook that could change only the comment notification recipient... You would probably need to overwrite some kind of core function, but here's a small workaround you could use:

**1.** Disable the email feature from WordPress comments settings (*unless you want to get notified too*)

**2.** Send it manually using the `comment_post` action hook. Just add this function to `functions.php`

```
    add_filter( 'comment_post', 'comment_notification' );

    function comment_notification( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {

        // Send email only when it's not approved
        if( $comment_approved == 0 ) {

            $subject = 'subject here';
            $message = 'message here';

            wp_mail( 'editor.email@here.com' , $subject, $message );
        }
    }

    // Remove if statement if you want to recive email even if it doesn't require moderation

`comment_post` is an action triggered immediately after a comment is inserted into the database.
```

Comment: **Never** change the core files. Your changes will be overwritten with the next WP update.  Filters are what is needed to change things.

Answer (score -1):

There is a filter for changing the text of the comment moderation email:

```
function change_comment_email( $body, $comment_id ) {
    $body = preg_replace( "/(A new )comment/s",  "$1review", $body );
    $body = preg_replace( "/(Currently \d+ )comment/s",  "$1review", $body );
    $body = preg_replace( "/Comment:/",  "Review:", $body );
    return $body;
}

add_filter( 'comment_moderation_text', 'change_comment_email', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_text', 'change_comment_email', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: That was not the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send this email to multiple people then use below code in functions.php -

```
function se_comment_moderation_recipients( $emails, $comment_id ) {

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
    $emails = array();
   // $users =  array(set of user IDs t whome you want to send mails)
    $users =  array( 1, 16628, 15983 );
    foreach($users as $uid){
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $uid );
    // Return emails of users .
         if ( !empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
           $emails[] =  $user->user_email;
        }
    }
    $emails_list = array(implode(",",$emails));
     return $emails_list;

}
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
```

Answer (score -2):

An alternative and more flexible way to the code hacking in the other answers is:

Create an email address for the admin account of the blog. For example, *site@your-blog.tld* that is different from *editor@your-blog.tld* and *technical@your-blog.tld*.

Option A: Forward site@ email to both the editor and the technical admin. I create site@ as an alias. This works if your editor is okay with receiving a copy of all the automatic email generated by the site. They just filter irrelevant email out or learn what actually happens with a site. This is good for small clients.

Option B: Set up a mail filter for site@ to automatically forward emails about comment alerts to the editor and all email to the technical admin. The technical admin can then filter to archive/delete all comment alerts so they never appear in their inbox. This initial forward to editor@ can be done on the mail server using something like [procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail). Alternatively you can do it on your email client if it's up 24/7 or you can even use Gmail, [Hotmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotmail), etc. and manually build the filter.

Comment: Gotta love a downvote on a 2.5 year old answer without a comment. Thanks Peter Mortensen for the edit